# Mac OS - Mojave- wxpython2.8 installation

Tags: python, macos, wxpython, macos-mojave

I have to run software (frontend of multiple R and Python libraries for NLP), that uses wxpython 2.8. My laptop is a Macbook air (Mojave), and I did not succeed in installing wxpython version 2.8. I went to the wxpython to download the dmg of the version I want, bypassed the security guards of the Mac, but can't succeed in installing it.

Has anybody succeeded in installing wxpython 2.8 on a Mac OS X Mojave? What's the process?

Answer (score 1):

Try to install it with [Homebrew](https://brew.sh)

`$brew install wxpython`

Comment: I respond with a big lapse of time. Sorry Mykola. But yes you are true. For some other Mac we will aso need wxmacs. By chance Brew install version 3 of wxpython which is ok for the software i have to use (Iramuteq=http://iramuteq.org/). ... Indeed, the software itself will need to upgrade its packages!^^ahahahaha